# ROS core commands missing after reinstall

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

after uninstalling ROS and then reinstalling ros-cturtle-pr2all (according to the instructions), all of the ROS core commands are missing on my system (all of rospack, rosmake etc. -- except for roslocate and rosinstall). Indeed, the entire ROS_ROOT directory (/opt/ros/cturtle/ros) is missing. On the other hand, /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks seems to be chock-full with stacks. The apt-get install command returns without errors, and the system claims that pr2all is completely installed.

I use Ubuntu 10.10.

Any ideas how I could get "apt-get" to perform a full (re)installation of ROS? That would be very kind.

Background info: The problem started because of my own stupidity. I seem to have made an unclean uninstall of ros-cturtle-pr2, when I simply deleted /opt/ros recursively as well as ROS files in my home folder. After that I have tried several times and in several ways to uninstall/reinstall ROS (cturtle-base / pr2 / pr2all), using both apt-get install/reinstall and the Ubuntu Software Center. The result is always the same: the installation appears to be successful, but there is no /opt/ros/cturtle/ros directory.

Best, Wendelin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9215/ros-core-commands-missing-after-reinstall/) by [Wendelin Reich](https://answers.ros.org/users/199/wendelin-reich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried "sudo apt-get remove ros-cturtle-ros"?   That should clear out everything and let you try again.  I would start with something smaller to start, like "sudo apt-get install ros-cturtle-common" (ros + common + common_msgs) to make sure the reinstall is working.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wendelin Reich](https://answers.ros.org/users/199/wendelin-reich/) on 2011-02-26**:
Yes, that fixed it - first apt-install of ros-cturtle-common, then of ros-cturtle-pr2all on top of it. Seems a bit strange, though. But I don't know how to reproduce the error, and it may be obsolete with the release of diamondback. So thanks!!